# Merge indexes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
>>> df
          item  count
id  month 
12  1     1351  19
          585   11 
    2     1350  2
          140   1
```

and another that has something like

```
>>> usermap
   id   age   gender
0  2    25    m
1  12   40    f
```

end result should be:

```
>>> df_merged
id  age  gender month  item  count
12  40   f       1     1351  19
                       585   11 
                 2     1350  2
                       140   1
```

I'm thinking I could do:

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, usermap, on='id', how='left')
df_merged = df_merged.set_index(['id','age','gender','month'])
```

but is there any better solution, especially for large dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
df = (df.join(usermap.set_index('id'))
        .set_index(['age','gender'], append=True)
        .reorder_levels(['id','age','gender','month']))
print (df)
                     item  count
id age gender month             
12 40  f      1      1351     19
              1       585     11
              2      1350      2
              2       140      1
```